# Trying to redirect all traffic on site to HTTP (non secure) via .HTACCESS but my rule always causes "The page can't be displayed"

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect all traffic for my domain to HTTP (non-SSL) and I've found various samples of how to do this, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
#RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But no matter what I try the page will not load with using the Rewrite rule, getting "The page cannot be displayed".

The HTTP URL that it redirected to in the address bar is correct.

This is a Drupal 7 website.

I've tried placing the rewrite code in the top, bottom and middle of the .HTACCESS file with the same results every time.

I'm out of ideas as to why it won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: That `#` does not belong there...

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't mean to put the # in the pasted code. I had commented it out on the live server because it was crashing the site and forgot to remove it when pasted here.

Comment: If the resulting URL in the browsers address bar is correct then the rewriting/redirecting is not the issue. There has to be some _other_ issue. You will have to do a bit of debugging: start by checking your http servers error log file.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I don't have access to the server setup (client does). This one is strange and looks like it's out of my control.